# Creating an animation that transforms location along local z axis

Tags: animation

I have a bunch of buttons set up at different locations and I'd like to animate them all using a single action map, but to do this I need to animate them all to move slightly down and up along their local z-axis, is there a way I can do this in blender?

Comment: Hello, have you tried a Transformation constraint?

Comment: or joining them?